# Passport.js not persisting on Firefox

Tags: node.js, redis, passport.js

I am using passport.js on a node server with local strategy, facebook and twitter.  Everything is working great except for one issue.  On firefox, if I close firefox and quit it, when I reopen it, the user I was logged on with is no longer logged in.  This does not happen on any other browsers.  I am doing all the standard passport stuff and persisting the session to redis.  Wondering if anyone else has had this issue.  Again, it is working correctly on all other browsers.

Comment: Is your session cookie still present?  Maybe firefox is just clearing your cookies.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the cookie setting in browser......

I think your setting will be something like this.....
"Clear cookies when browser close", if so change it and try...